# Como passar o codigo em matrícula como parâmetro da função?

Tags: c, array, funções

Tenho que ordenar de forma decrescente os salários dos funcionarios de uma empresa.
***Entrada:*** *Matrícula, salário, se deseja continuar*
***Saída:*** *Salários em ordem decrescente.*
O erro que está aparecendo é o seguite:

> [Warning] passing argument 1 of 'le_valida_matricula' makes integer
>   from pointer without a cast

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* 
Lucas Correia Barros Lauriano
Síntese
Objetivo: Ordenar de forma decrescente os salários dos funcionarios de uma empresa
Entrada: Matrícula, salário, se deseja continuar
Saída: Salários em ordem decrescente

*/


char valida_caracter(char opc1, char opc2, char titulo[]);
int le_valida_matricula(int mat, char titulo[]);

int main() {

    char matricula_func[0];
    float salario_func[0];
    char opc;



    do{


        matricula_func = le_valida_matricula(matricula_func, "Informe a matricula do funcionario: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Informe o salario do funcionario:");
        scanf("%d", &salario_func);



        opc = valida_caracter('s', 'n', "Pressione S para continuar");

        system("cls");
    }while(opc == 's');

    return 0;
}

char valida_caracter(char opc1, char opc2, char titulo[]){
    char opc;
    do{ 
    printf(titulo);
    opc = getch();
    fflush(stdin);
    opc = tolower(opc);

    if(opc !='s' && opc!= 'n'){
        system("cls");
        printf("Opcao invalida! Digite %c ou %c que sao opcoes valida\n", opc1, opc2);
    }
    }while(opc !='s' && opc!= 'n');

    return opc;
}

int le_valida_matricula(int mat, char titulo[]){

    int aux;

    do{
        printf(titulo);
        scanf("%d", &aux);

        if(aux == '\0')
            {
                printf("Deve ser diferente de vazio!");
            }

    }while(aux == '\0');

    return aux; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente você estava tentando passar uma variavel como parametro sem ter dado um valor pra ela, e estava fazendo ela mesmo receber o que a função retornava, aqui:
 `matricula_func = le_valida_matricula(matricula_func, "Informe a matricula do funcionario: ");`

Segundo, você não estava definindo qual posição do vetor queria atribuir um valor. Tomei a liberdade de criar uma variavel de contagem `i`. E coloquei a chamada da função `le_valida_matricula()` sem dependencia de parametros, fiz o que você estava fazendo porém dentro da própria função.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* 
Lucas Correia Barros Lauriano
Síntese
Objetivo: Ordenar de forma decrescente os salários dos funcionarios de uma empresa
Entrada: Matrícula, salário, se deseja continuar
Saída: Salários em ordem decrescente

*/


char valida_caracter(char opc1, char opc2, char titulo[]){
    char opc;
    do{ 
    printf(titulo);
    opc = getch();
    fflush(stdin);
    opc = tolower(opc);

    if(opc !='s' && opc!= 'n'){
        system("cls");
        printf("Opcao invalida! Digite %c ou %c que sao opcoes valida\n", opc1, opc2);
    }
    }while(opc !='s' && opc!= 'n');

    return opc;
}

int le_valida_matricula(){

    int aux;

    do{
        printf("Qual a matricula do funcionario?");
        scanf("%d", &aux);

        if(aux == '\0')
            {
                printf("Deve ser diferente de vazio!");
            }

    }while(aux == '\0');

    return aux; 
}

int main() {

    char matricula_func[0];
    float salario_func[0];
    char opc;
    int i=0;



    do{


        matricula_func[i] = le_valida_matricula();
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Informe o salario do funcionario:");
        scanf("%d", &salario_func);
        i++;


        opc = valida_caracter('s', 'n', "Pressione S para continuar");

        system("cls");
    }while(opc == 's');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Valeu, Eduardo! Vou dar uma olhada no código mais tarde. E tentar entender o que você fez também. Eu ainda tenho que fazer muita coisa, mas se eu entender esse primeiro exercício corretamente, já é meio caminho andado.